# How to select top x records for every group

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by, having

I tried something like this

```
select Id,UserId from myTable group by Id,UserId having COUNT(UserId)<7
```

Now what i want to do is selecting 6 records for each userid. But my approach failed.

So what is the correct syntax ?

Id is primary key clustered index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you pretty close

```
WITH    r ( userid, rnk )
      AS ( SELECT   userid, RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ) AS rnk
           FROM     MyTable 
           GROUP BY userid)
SELECT  r.*
FROM    r
WHERE   r.Rank <= 6
```