# sqlite: get the average of the top X% for every item

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to get the average of the top X% items in a group?

For example:
I have a table which has a item_id, timestamp and price column. The output should be grouped by item_id and timestamp and the 'price-column' should get averaged. For the averaging only the lowest X% prices within that group should be used.

I've found similar questions ([How to select top x records for every group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025255/how-to-select-top-x-records-for-every-group)) but this won't work with sqlite.

Comment: What do you mean with "lowest X% prices"? What is the basis of the percentage? Price? Count? Could you show an example?

Comment: Does it make sense to group by a timestamp? Can you put into clearer words what you are trying to achieve--what the query should return?

Comment: @Tim yes it makes sense in my case because there are a number of items which have the absolutly same timestamp (because they were inserted/updated as a batch)

Comment: @CL it's based on the count of records (sorry for the misunderstanding)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting the top n records within each group requires counting.  Assuming that there are no duplicates, the following query returns the number of records for an item:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.item_id = t.item_id
       ) as NumPrices
from t
```

This is called a *correlated subquery*.  Now, let's extend the idea to include a rank and then calculate the average for the right group:

```
select item_id, avg(price)
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.item_id = t.item_id
             ) as NumPrices,
             (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.item_id = t.item_id and t2.price <= t.price
             ) as PriceRank
      from t
     ) t
where (100.0*PriceRank / NumPrices) <= X
group by item_id
```

To improve performance, you will want an index on `(item_id, price)`.

Comment: I've tried that and - while the query itself makes sense - it's super slow (didn't finish after 10 minutes). my table has ~1000000 records which should get grouped to ~8000 records. I will accept the answer anyway if there won't be anything better

Comment: currently only an index on the price column

Comment: @Daniel . . . Try it with the suggested index.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your suggestion but it's still slow as hell. When i remove the "where-clause" i get fast results but it could be that it's still calculating in the background or something.

Answer (score 1):

To get the count of records in the group with ID `I` and timestamp `T`, use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
WHERE item_id = I
  AND timestamp = T
```

To get the limit, multiply with `X`, and use `ROUND`/`CAST` to convert to an integer:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(COUNT(*) * X / 100) AS INTEGER)
FROM MyTable
WHERE item_id = I
  AND timestamp = T
```

To get all records in a specific group that are inside that limit, order the records in the group by price, and limit the returned count:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE item_id = I
  AND timestamp = T
ORDER BY price
LIMIT (SELECT CAST(ROUND(COUNT(*) * X / 100) AS INTEGER)
       FROM MyTable
       WHERE item_id = I
         AND timestamp = T)
```

In theory, to get the group averages, add `GROUP BY` around that:

```
SELECT item_id,
       timestamp,
       (SELECT AVG(price)
        FROM (SELECT price
              FROM MyTable T2
              WHERE T2.item_id = T1.item_id
                AND T2.timestamp = T1.timestamp
              ORDER BY price
              LIMIT (SELECT CAST(ROUND(COUNT(*) * X / 100) AS INTEGER)
                     FROM MyTable T3
                     WHERE T3.item_id = T1.item_id
                       AND T3.timestamp = T1.timestamp)
             )
       ) AS AvgPriceLowestX
FROM MyTable T1
GROUP BY item_id,
         timestamp
```

However, it appears that SQLite does not allow access to correlation variables from inside the `LIMIT` clause, so this does not work in practice.
You would have to get the IDs of all groups (`SELECT DISTINCT item_id, timestamp FROM MyTable`) and execute the third query above for each group.

In any case, ensure that you have one index on the three columns `item_id`, `timestamp`, and `price` to get good performance.